# Problem with HHL algorithm on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, hhl-algorithm

I try to run HHL algorithm on quantum computer in Qiskit Notebooks on the site. I take it from here https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html but it doesn't work. The error message is 
 `"Credentials are already in use. The existing account in the session will be replaced."` and `"circuits = [qc_qa_c, qc_qa_3cx, qc_qa_5cx]"`

Answer (score 7):

These aren't error messages, they are just outputs. The first message simply means it will be using your credentials for the session. This has probably popped up because you have run `IBMQ.load_accounts()` more than once. The second message appears to just be the output of the creation of the `circuits` variable.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I had IBMQ.load_accounts(). And yes. In this textbook they don't describe about shots, and add in circuits `[qc_qa_3cx, qc_qa_5cx]` but they don't declare it.